# Codeigniter: Passing data from parent controller constructor to view( Undefined variable error )

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

**MyController:**

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

        public $data = array();

        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->data['errors'] = array();
            $this->data['site_name'] = config_item('site_name');
        }

}
```

**AdminController:**

```
class Admin_Controller extends MY_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct ();
        $this->data ['meta_title'] = 'Admin Panel';
        $this->load->helper ( 'form' );
        $this->load->library ( 'form_validation' );
    }
}
```

**UserController:**

```
class User extends Admin_Controller {

        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function login() {
            $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/user/login';
            $this->load->view('admin/_layout_modal', $this->data);
        }
         }
```

**View: _layout_modal.php**

```
$this->load->view($subview);
echo $meta_title;
```

But both $subview and $meta_title are throwing  "Undefined variable" error.

**A PHP Error was encountered**

**Severity: Notice**

**Message: Undefined variable: subview**

**Filename: admin/_layout_modal.php**

Comment: any suggestions at all? I'm breaking my head from 24hrs to fix this

Comment: Where is your adminController placed?

Answer (score 1):

In default, $this->load->view send the data to browser directly.

It seems you want to load view as string format, not sending to browser directly.

You need to add one parameter to the 'view' function

I think you should change your codes like this:

UserController:

```
    public function login() {
        $this->data['subview'] = $this->load->view('admin/user/login', true);
        $this->load->view('admin/_layout_modal', $this->data);
    }
```

View: _layout_modal.php

```
echo $subview;
echo $meta_title;
```

Reference:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html

Comment: OP's storing the _name_ of the view inside the $subview variable, and loading the child view inside the main view using that _name_ . While your answer is technically right, also is OP's code

Comment: Yeah! His approach is also right. There are many ways, that's cool. But in the view page I'm stuck at Undefined variable error, even though I've added $this->data in the controller. I shoud'nt be getting that error. Somehow this line is not doing it's job right: $this->load->view('admin/_layout_modal', $this->data);

Answer (score 0):

try to use `$data['subview']` not `$this->data['subview']` and when loading the view you use `$this->load->view('admin/layout',$data);` and in layout file call `<?php echo $subview; ?>`